# how do I set up multiple queues in laravel queue.php

Tags: laravel, amazon-sqs

I am trying to set up multiple queues in my queue.php in laravel.

Documentation found specifies how to set up a queue, and talks about multiple queues, but does not specify how to set them up in queue.php

```
  'sqs-fifo' => [
        'driver' => 'sqs-fifo',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'prefix' => env('SQS_PREFIX', 'myqueurl'),
        'queue' => env('SQS_QUEUE', 'queue1.fifo'),
        'suffix' => env('SQS_SUFFIX'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'ap-northeast-1'),
        'group' => 'default',
        'deduplicator' => 'unique'
    ],
```

Where do I specify the name of other queues?

Comment: that is a name right there 'sqs-fifo'  ... the keys of the 'connections' array are the names

Answer (score 2):

Laravel documentation doesnt specify this, but if you have created multiple queues in Amazon SQS, for example:

queue1.fifo
queue2.fifo
queue3.fifo

You only need to configure your default queue in the queue.php file, and are free to queue jobs to the other queues that you have created in Amazon SQS simply by specifying their name.  No need to add it to a config file.

Example:

```
ProcessMyJob::dispatch()->onQueue('queue2.fifo');
```

In the example above, you can see I am telling the job dispatching the "ProcessMyJob" Job, on a queue called 'queue2.fifo', that I have set up on Amazon SQS.